# Insert info from one report to an empty report with only headers

Tags: sql-server

I will try and explain my query as best I can. I am using SQL Server and currently I now have one output report (call it Report A) with numerous headers and values in the rows, the values in the rows (not the headers) from Report A must be inserted in another report (Call it Report B), however Report B is empty with no values in the rows and only headers, the header names are also different from Report A. I have considered altering Report A to have the same headers as B and to replicate B, but it is not technically the correct way of doing it.

Here is an example of what I require.

**REPORT A**

```
    Mem-Num|  Total|  Address|  Dep|  Contact Number|  Scheme Code|
    123       R100    Gauteng   00    12345678910      16
```

**REPORT B - NO VALUES ONLY HEADERS**

```
    Member Number|  Product Code|  Total|  Banking Details
```

**OUTPUT TO BE REPORT B WITH VALUES OF REPORT A**

```
    Member Number|  Product Code|  Total|  Banking Details
    123             16             R100    Field will be Blank
```

**THUS**

```
    Report B (Member Number)     = Report A (Mem-num),
    Report B (Product Code)      = Report A (Scheme Code),       
    Report B (Total)             = Report A (Total),       
    Report B (Banking Details)   = Blank 
    There is no data in Report A to insert into Report B for Banking Details
```

Comment: Include a column-mapping as part of whatever process you are using to transfer the values to ReportB.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand you write, why not just do this ?

```
Select Mem-Num as 'Member Number'
        ,Scheme Code 'Product Code'
        ,Total
        ,Null
From(
Select Mem-Num,  Total, Scheme Code
from ReportA_table) a
```

Comment: Won't this then just alter Report A and not update the data into Report B? Sorry still new at this. I am reading up on the column mapping suggestion but a bit high level for me.

Comment: When you say report do you mean report like SSRS ? Or are you just saying the query results? You should be able to have multiple sources in whatever reporting software you using, this will give you the same results but with different column names

Comment: Yes I am referring the the query result. Okay will give it a go.